# Game over pop-up like Flappy Bird

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, flappy-bird-clone

How can I make a game over pop-up like Flappy Bird in cocos2d-iphone 3?

[image]

I tried to add a new Scene, but it adds a new screen on the game, I just want a rectangle with some buttons inside it.
I also search how to add multiple scene, but didn't find an example doing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a `CCNode`. Create your own class - `GameOverNode` which subclasses  `CCNode`, then you want to add buttons and your images to this `GameOverNode`.

When you need to create the `GameOverNode` and show it to the user, you simply initialise it and add it to your `CCScene`.

Edit: Changed CCLayer to CCNode as per changes in the cocos2Diphone documentation - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/3.0-rc1/Classes/CCScene.html

```
@interface GameOverNode : CCNode {
    CCButton *_aButton;
    CCSprite *_aSprite;
    CCLabelTTF *_aLabel;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCButton *aButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *aSprite;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCLabelTTF *aLabel;

@end
```

Then inside the implementation of your GameOverNode:

```
@implementation GameOverNode


-(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init] ){
        //initialise your buttons, labels, sprites
        //add them to your node
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Finally in your CCScene. Initialise your GameOverNode and add it to the scene

```
 GameOverNode *gameOverNode = [GameOverNode alloc];
 [gameOverNode init];
 [self addChild:gameOverNode];
```

Comment: thanks for the help! Can you give an example how it would be done?

Comment: CCLayer? In Cocos2d v3 its not there.

Comment: Yep, mistake - CCLayer has been removed. Use a CCNode instead.